# On Finite Extensions(Abstract Algebra)

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I am working with the following theorem.

Let $F, E$ and $K$ be fields such that $F \leq E \leq K \leq \overline{F}$. Suppose $K$ is a finite extension field of $F$.  Suppose $K$ is a splitting field over $F$ and $E$ is a splitting field over $F$.
Then  $|G(K/F)|=|G(K/E)||G(E/F)|$.

May concern is whether the following implication is correct:
If $K$ is a finite extension field of $F$ and  $F \leq E \leq K$, then $E$ is also a finite extension of $F$.

The thought I am using is... 'extending a basis A of a vector space $V_1$
to obtain finite dimensional vector space $V_2$ with basis B' wherein $V_1 \subseteq V_2$ will suggest that A is finite. Is this alright?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that $K$ and $E$ are, besides fields, vector spaces over $F$.
From linear algebra, we know that if $K$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $F$, then any subspace $E\le K$ is also a finite-dimensional vector space over $F$.

You may want to review that part of linear algebra for the proof.
Basically, the idea is that any basis of $E$ can be extended to a basis of $K$,
but if a basis $S$ of $E$ is infinite,
that would mean the basis of $K$ resulted from the extension of $S$ is also infinite,
contradicting the finite dimension of $K$.

---

The assumption that $K$ is a finite extension over $F$ is redundant.
Any splitting field over $F$ is automatically a finite extension.
In fact, its degree is bounded above by the factorial of the degree of the polynomial for which it is a splitting field.

Comment: I think  I used the correct though process as supported by your answer. Thank you very much. 
 I just want to comment on the 'foot note'. I know also that  we need  K to be separable for |G(K/F)|=[K:F] but it is not necessary in the theorem since what we have are |G(K/E)| and |G(E/F)| not [K:E] and [E:F]. What I used actually is the equation {K:F}={K:E}{E:F} to prove the theorem [Fraleigh, Definition 49.9, page 428; index of E over F].

Comment: @Zai Ahh, my bad. You are right on that. Updated.